# Swift heightForRow with condition checking after cell deletion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a dataSource checking to define the cellHeightForRowAt delegate

All the codes are working well with addition of the cell, but not deletion

here are my codes

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dataSource.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if self.dataSource[indexPath.row].isExclusive {
        return 280.0
    }
    else {
        return 150.0
    }
}

fileprivate func handleCellDeletion(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let cellIndexPath = self.paymentMethodTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    guard let indexPath = cellIndexPath else { return }

    self.dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.paymentMethodTableView.beginUpdates()
    self.paymentMethodTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    self.paymentMethodTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Now, the problem is whenever a cell is deleted, it will run the heightForRowAt delegate again, and this line of code will throw index out of range exception

```
if self.dataSource[indexPath.row].isExclusive { // <== this will throw exception
```

I notice that somehow the indexPath.row still reflect the total row before the deletion, even though I have already removed the index in my dataSource array before reloadingRows

Anyone can guide me please? What am I missing here? Thanks

Comment: You don't need the calls to `begin/endUpdates`.

Comment: hi @maddy thanks for the response. I have removed the begin/updates but still give me index out of range exception

Comment: @Alvin You may need to first `deleteRows` then `remove`. Try switching `self.dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)` and `self.paymentMethodTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)`, and remove `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`

```
fileprivate func handleCellDeletion(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let cellIndexPath = self.paymentMethodTableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    guard let indexPath = cellIndexPath else { return }

    self.dataSource.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: As stated in the comments, removing the calls to `begin|endUpdates` doesn't resolve the issue (even though they are not needed). It seems your code will work simply because you replaced the call to `deleteRows` with `reloadData`. While this works, it *shouldn't* be necessary and it doesn't explain what is wrong with the OP's code.